# Windows 7 is taking too long to boot and to open profile

Tags: windows-7, boot, user-profiles

It's taking some minutes until my windows 7 load. Then it asks for my password. After I enter the password it takes 1 minute or more to load the basic and some more minutes to start everything.

This is my Startup Services and Programs

[image: services and startup items]

Is there something wrong with it? It wasn't so slow a while ago.

I have run some **cleans on registry and files with CCleaner**.

Is my profile corrupted or something like it? What should I do?

My config: Quad Core 2.0 GHz, 6 GB RAM, 3 GB Video

Comment: I guess this is related, but I couldn't get a clear answer from it. http://forums.techguy.org/windows-xp/789702-solved-windows-starting-up-screen.html

Comment: Those cleanups of the Registry are probably what did it.

Comment: @Randolph: What can I do to fix it? Any idea?

Comment: I would create a new user profile and use that as a test to see if it is still as slow. If not, then your registry is probably corrupt, and you could use the new profile instead. If it is equally slow, then it points to another problem.

Comment: @Randolph: I've confirmed this. I've created a new account and restarted the PC 2 times. It took a lot to load everything, so it really is my registry. Any idea on how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only recommendation, based on our conversation in the comments, is to roll back to before the CCleaner installation using System Restore.

Comment: CCleaner is very unlikely to be the issue, make sure you defrag and try http://www.soluto.com/ their program shows you how long every item takes to load and gives you options of how to deal with them

Answer (score 2):

Download [Autoruns from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx):

Instruct it to hide all core operating system items (Options -> Hide Windows Entries):
[image]

Starting with the `Logon` tab, decide which programs you want to start with Windows. There's only going to be 3 or 4 that you actually use; uncheck the rest.
[image]

Next visit the `Services` tab, where you'll see all the services that you don't need.

> **Note:** Don't "uncheck" services, but instead use use Computer Management to change their startup from **Automatic** to **Manual**

[image]

> **Note:** You'll see other services by **Microsoft**. In step 1 you hid services that are part of the operating system. These are different from services not part of Windows: such as services written by Apple, nVidia, and Microsoft. If it's a core Windows service, you leave it alone. If it's a non-Windows service, it's fair game for manual startup.

Additionally, all real-time virus checking software kills performance of any computer. Turn off real-time scanning, file scanning, network scanning, proxying, e-mail proxying, etc. If you feel as though you engage in risky enough behavior to need a virus scanner: schedule a scan for when you're not using your computer.

---

**Short version:** Get rid of junk. Windows runs fine, 3rd party baggage slows it down.

Answer (score 1):

dude, u hav too many start up services running. disable the services like MS office 2010..all, java, fastone, hp media smart tv, tv taskschedular, and ,many more............

Comment: Lmao I didn't even look at the screenshots when i read this the first time just wow :(

Comment: That is not the issue.